# How to count the number of commit in gitlab using Python?

Tags: python, scripting, gitlab, repository

I am manager of several projects (+-80) on GitLab and I have to count the number of commits that each one of the members did?
Currently I can access the repositories using `Repo.Clone_from()` for copying the repositories to the local machine. 
Is there any way to iterate over all the projects and extract this information from them ?

Answer (score 1):

As i understand from the problem you want to extract the count of the commits each project have

You can achieve this using python gitlab module:

```
import gitlab

gl = gitlab.Gitlab(git_url, private_token=your_private_token)
projects = group.projects.list()
all_projects = group.projects.list(all=True)
length=len(all_projects)
i=0
while i < length:
    project = gl.projects.get(all_projects[i].id)
    gitlab_commits = project.commits.list()
    commits_length=len(gitlab_commits)
    i=i+1
```

Comment: This gives commit of each project

Comment: you can specify branch also as: gitlab_commits = project.commits.list(ref_name="branch_name")

Comment: What is the package to use "import gitlab" ? Where does the "group" variable come from ?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are using the GitLab api on python, so if it's you can do something like this:

```
repos = []; page = 0
while True:
  next_list = gl.projects.all(per_page=50, page=page)
  if not next_list:
    break
  repos.extend(next_list)
  page += 1
```